# How to resolve discrepancy between type system and runtime behavior?

Tags: typescript

I have defined a TypeScript type `Awaitable<T>` as shown below, with the intention of making `Awaited<Awaitable<T>>` equivalent to `T`.

```js
export type Awaitable<T> =
  | (T extends Record<'then', Function> ? never : T)
  | PromiseLike<T>;
```

In the following code, I encountered a type error indicating that a certain comparison would not evaluate to true. However, when running the compiled code, the comparison does evaluate to true.

```js
(async () => {
  const something = {
    then: <T>(callback: (value: { data: false }) => PromiseLike<T>) => callback({ data: false }),
    data: true,
  } as const satisfies PromiseLike<{ data: false }> & { data: true };
  const typed: Awaitable<{ data: true }> = something;
  const awaited = await typed;
  if (awaited.data === false) { // This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types 'true' and 'false' have no overlap. (2367)
    console.log("so, this would never printed. right?");
  }
})();
```

Is there a way to prevent this discrepancy between the TypeScript type system and the actual runtime behavior?

I can't think of any solution, I'm just stuck. I don't know if this is even possible...

**Edit**

The problem is that the function below can return a value different from its type.

```js
async function AcceptsAwaitable<T>(awaitable: Awaitable<T>): Promise<T> {
  return await awaitable;
}
```

Comment: I... why are you doing this?  TS isn't always type safe, so the issue you're exposing will probably just come down to some operation which is usually a widening but in this situation is not.  But right now it looks like you're intentionally crafting a pathological object. Why? Is there a more natural situation in which this arises? Like, if you were to file this as a bug in TS, they'd say "when does this actually happen in real world code", since they care more about improving the average developer experience than avoiding unusual corner cases.

Answer (score 0):

You typed `typed` with `Awaitable<{ data: true }>`, which mean that the type of `data` is not `boolean`, but `true`, and therefore it cannot be false. If the value can be either `true` or `false` the type should be `Awaitable<{data: boolean}>`

Comment: I edited my question.

The problem is that some function can return a value different from its type.

Comment: Why would that happen ?

Comment: When an object is a certain value (`T`) while simultaneously being a `PromiseLike<U>` for another value. in case of my question's code, `T` is `{ data: true }` and `U` is `{ data: false }`.

Answer (score 0):

I think an explicit type assertion can solve this.

```
async function AcceptsAwaitable<T>(awaitable: Awaitable<T>): Promise<T> {
   return await awaitable as Promise<T>; // explicit type assertion
}
```

Comment: The `awaitable` can be a `T` with `then` property, then it will resolved to value other than `T`...